# I want to create individual text file for each link of the headings and write the article of the headings to those text files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wanted the articles/paragraphs for each headings to be written on different text files matching the names of the headings serial numbers inside another file. I think I made some mistake and now the headings are also not being printed correctly but the paragraphs are being printed correctly. I think there is something wrong with the order of codes I've written.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s_date = '2018/01/01'
e_date = '2018/01/02'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
delta = timedelta(days = 1)

date_list =  list()
while d1 <= d2:
    date_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    d1 += delta
print(date_list)
count = 0
with open('head.txt', 'w') as f:
    for d in date_list:
        URL = 'https://www.thedailystar.net/newspaper?date={}'.format(d)
        result = requests.get(URL)
        src = result.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        containers = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'list-content')
        key_words = ['Road', 'crash', 'dead', 'accidents']
    #    key_word = input('Enter the desired word to search the news: ')
        for c in containers:
            headings = c.h5.a.text
            if any(key_word in headings for key_word in key_words):
                print(headings)
                f.write(str(count) + headings + '    ' + URL + '    ' + '---------> ' + d + '\n')
                count += 1
                for articles in containers:
                    ar = articles.h5.a.attrs['href']
                    article = requests.get('https://www.thedailystar.net{}'.format(ar))
                    p_src = article.text
                    p_soup = BeautifulSoup(p_src, 'lxml')
                    p_content = p_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'field-body view-mode-full')
                    for p in p_content:
                        paragraph = p.text
#                        print(paragraph)
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Should be correct (again if I understood your task properly):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s_date = '2018/01/01'
e_date = '2018/01/02'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
delta = timedelta(days = 1)

date_list =  list()
while d1 <= d2:
    date_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    d1 += delta
print(date_list)
count = 0
key_words = ['Road', 'crash', 'dead', 'accidents']

with open('head.txt', 'w') as f:
    for d in date_list:
        URL = 'https://www.thedailystar.net/newspaper?date={}'.format(d)
        result = requests.get(URL)
        src = result.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        containers = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'list-content')
        
        for c in containers:
            headings = c.h5.a.text
            if any(key_word in headings for key_word in key_words):
                print(headings)
                f.write(str(count) + headings + '    ' + URL + '    ' + '---------> ' + d + '\n')
                count += 1
                if 'href' in c.h5.a.attrs:
                    ar = c.h5.a.attrs['href']
                    with open(str(count) + '.txt') as temp_f:
                        article = requests.get('https://www.thedailystar.net{}'.format(ar))
                        p_src = article.text
                        p_soup = BeautifulSoup(p_src, 'lxml')
                        p_content = p_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'field-body view-mode-full')
                        for p in p_content:
                            [tag_wrapper.decompose() for tag_wrapper in p.find_all('div', class_ = 'dfp-tag-wrapper')]
                            paragraph = p.text
#                            print(paragraph)
                            temp_f.write(paragraph)
```

You missed `open`ing separate files for article contents. Also you were looping twice over `containers` objject, which is incorrect.

I added an `if` statement to check wherther `href` is presented in `articles.h5.a.attrs`, because if `href` wouldn't be there, you'll get error, it's worth handling such moments in a safer mode.

Comment: The solution you provided is close but, what I wanted was the headings will be saved in a single text file with the serial numbers and for each headings I will get another text file with the headings serial as the name and it will save the inner content of the of the link that the heading contains. I did update my code but It's not giving me the exact results.  Shall I edit my code and you can check it again?

Comment: @SilviaIslamEera yep, update your code, let's see what you've done=)

Comment: I just updated it. Can you check it out please.

Comment: @SilviaIslamEera updated my answer, check it out

Comment: It sends out an error :'(                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 34, in <module>
    if 'href' in articles.h5.a.attrs:
NameError: name 'articles' is not defined

Comment: @SilviaIslamEera oops, fixed now, I forgot to replace it on `containers`

Comment: @SilviaIslamEera found another mistake, please check again if it works now

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it too, and solved it myself this morning. Thank you, I posted my code down in the comments. you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it myself. Here is what I did.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s_date = '2018/01/01'
e_date = '2018/01/02'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
delta = timedelta(days = 1)

date_list =  list()
while d1 <= d2:
    date_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    d1 += delta
print(date_list)
count = 1
key_words = ['Road', 'crash', 'dead', 'accidents']

with open('head.txt', 'w') as f:
    for d in date_list:
        URL = 'https://www.thedailystar.net/newspaper?date={}'.format(d)
        result = requests.get(URL)
        src = result.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        containers = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'list-content')

        for c in containers:
            headings = c.h5.a.text
            if any(key_word in headings for key_word in key_words):
                print(headings)
                ar = c.h5.a.attrs.get('href')
                p_link = 'https://www.thedailystar.net{}'.format(ar)
                article = requests.get(p_link)
                f.write(str(count) + headings + '    ' +  p_link  + '    ' + '---------> ' + d + '\n')
                count += 1
                with open(str(count) + '.txt', 'w') as temp_f:
#                    ar = c.h5.a.attrs.get('href')
#                    article = requests.get('https://www.thedailystar.net{}'.format(ar))
                    p_src = article.text
                    p_soup = BeautifulSoup(p_src, 'lxml')
                    p_content = p_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'field-body view-mode-full')
                    for p in p_content:
                        paragraph = p.text
#                            print(paragraph)
                        temp_f.write(paragraph)
```